# How to enable "Go To App" button on Pages Timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Does anyone know how to enable/add "Go To App" button to the new Page Timeline? Just like what BranchOut has on [their page](http://www.facebook.com/Branchout) next to the Like button?

Comment: I am curious about the same thing, hopefully someone knows the answer.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this? It seems to me that FB can enable this for "large" apps - perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. You have to go to the page's settings and in the Basic information section set the first dropdown list to Brands & Products and the second dropdown to Apps. Then the Go to app button will finally be visible.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but there's no way to enter our app ID once I select that and the "go to app" button still doesn't show up on our page http://www.facebook.com/realestateagentdirectory. It seems that I need to connect our page with our app that the "go to app" button should go to. Right?